# Java mail API works on localhost bu not on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a sending email logic using Java Mail API and it works fine when I am on localhost but once deployed on google cloud platform, the email goes to my servlet but never gets delivered.
I bought the email from GoDaddy so it's: xxx@mydomain.com.
After reading docs on google cloud platform and some comments here on StackOverflow, I have configured firewall rules but nothing seems to work to allow ingress and egress on port 25, 465 and 587 (I know google doesn't allow traffic on port 25).
I don't wanna use 3rd party email senders like sendbird... because I was using elastic before and I didn't need a 3rd party email sender, JavaMail was enough.
So I think Java mail should be enough for GCP.
Can anyone help me out?
Here is my sending email logic

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

/**
 *
 * @author sidibe ibrahim
 * Sending email logic
 */
public class EmailSender {

    static MessagingException me;

    public static boolean sendMail(String from, String password, String message, String to[], String title) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String host = "smtpout.secureserver.net";
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", 465);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "*");
        
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
        try {
            mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from, "xxx"));
            InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < to.length; i++) {
                toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; i++) {
                mimeMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
            }
            //sdd subject
            mimeMessage.setSubject(title);

            //set message to mimeMessage
            mimeMessage.setText(message, "UTF-8", "html");
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(host, from, password);
            transport.sendMessage(mimeMessage, mimeMessage.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
            return true;
        } catch (MessagingException m) {
            me.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The App Engine [Mail API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mail) *(which also supports [JavaMail](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mail/sending-mail-with-mail-api))* has already been deprecated.

Instead, GCP [recommends](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/java-differences#mail) to use a third-party mail provider such as:

- [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/)
- [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/)
- [Mailjet](https://www.mailjet.com/)

---

**EDIT**

If you would still like to continue with the outdated solution, however, see the [article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mail/sending-mail-with-mail-api#sending_email_messages) on sending emails with the Mail API.

Comment: thanks for your answer Denis, I have tried this but it does not work, I think these steps are intended to receive emails, what I want is to send emails from my app for example sending confirmation email after payment to customers who have purchased something.

Comment: You're correct - that was the article for receiving emails. I've updated my answer linking the one for sending emails instead. Please keep in mind that since this solution is deprecated, it is not officially supported by the GCP and you may experience some inconsistencies using it.